# change backgroundColor in activity from another activity android

Tags: android

I'd like to change background in **MainActivity** . color will be taken from another activity **Main3Activity**. Im trying to use onActivityResult but I dont have experience in that.

After ***onClick*** on the image that changes the color in **Main3Activity**

Can anyone help me?

screen shot of **Main3Activity**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJEfG.png][1]

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RelativeLayout wallpaper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wallpaper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    }

    public void getwallpaper(View v) {
        Intent Getwallpaper = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        startActivityForResult(Getwallpaper, 2);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (data != null) {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.item1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**Main3Activity:**

```
import static android.graphics.Color.RED;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView green;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        green = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.green);

        green.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Color", GREEN);
                setResult(2, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like -

```
int colour = intent.getIntExtra("Color", Color.WHITE);
findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(colour);
```

or

```
int colour = intent.getIntExtra("Color", Color.WHITE);
View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setBackgroundColor(colour);
```